# Simple Javascript - HTML5 audio, call function 20 seconds before .ended

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to call a function (just an alert for now) at a specific time before an audio clip ends (20 seconds here). for some reason it's not working, and after troubleshooting for quiet a while I still don't know why it doesn't work. here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/QUkHQ/

```
<audio id="track" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-    sample.ogg"
       ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = this.currentTime     + ' / ' + this.duration;">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
<span id="tracktime" style="display:block;width:100px;">0 / 0</span>  
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').play();">Play</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').pause();">Pause</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').currentTime = 10;">skip</button>
<span id="time" onclick="this.innerHTML = document.getElementById('track').currentTime     ;"> n/a </span>
<script>
document.getElementById("track").addEventListener('timeupdate',checkdif,false)

x=document.getElementById('track');

function checkdif()
{
// alert(document.getElementById('track').currentTime);
document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = x.duration-x.currentTime};
if (x.duration-x.currentTime<20)
{
alert(); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Example: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/Y2BCP/

The problem is in the conditional: `if (x.duration-x.currentTime<20)`, as when I stored a variable `currentTime` then checked that is was less than 20, I got the expected results. Also, I didn't see the use for having a separate `ontimeupdate` and `addEventListener`, so I moved everything into a function that is called by the event listener.

Also I would suggest moving your script into an external file, so that your HTML is not bloated with scripts.

## Javascript (make sure its in the head):

```
var alertSent = false;
var obj = document.getElementById('track');
document.getElementById("track").addEventListener('timeupdate', checkTime, false)

function checkTime() {
    document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = obj.currentTime + ' / ' + obj.duration;
    var timeRemaining = obj.duration - obj.currentTime;
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = timeRemaining;
    if (timeRemaining < 20 && !alertSent) {
        alert("Hello");
        alertSent = true;
    }
}
```

## HTML:

```
<audio id="track" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
<span id="tracktime" style="display:block;width:100px;">0 / 0</span>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').play();">Play</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').pause();">Pause</button>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').currentTime = 10;">skip</button>
<span id="time"> n/a </span>
```